# Relative path works but Absolute path doesn't work

Tags: php

I am a newbie in php and I have a little struggle with making a project work .
my project folders are displayed like this:

```
-> Project
    ->doc1
    ->web
        *page1.php
        ->menu
            *menu.php
```

I tried accessing menu.php in my file page1.php using relative path like this:

```
@require "menu/menu.php";
```

And it works. But when I try to use absolute path like this:

```
@require "/project/web/menu/menu.php";
```

it doesn't work for me. I don't know where the problem exactly comes from. I hope someone can guide me and show me where I missed up or what do I need to verify to fix the problem.

P.S: the reason I wanted to use absolute path because the project get messed up moving from a directory to another, so I want to make it all absolute path so I don't get confused since I am just starting using php.

Comment: Absolute paths are absolute from the root of the file system, not of the project. Is that where you're getting confused?

Comment: _“the reason I wanted to use absolute path because the project get messed up moving from a directory to another”_ - that is, generally speaking, a reason _for_ using relative paths, not against. If you moved the whole project to a different folder - and not just parts of it - then you should not have any such problems to begin with.

Comment: If you want to use absolute paths, then you should at least make the first part of those come from a constant, that gets set to the project’s base path early on in a configuration file or something like that. Otherwise, if you completely hard-code the complete paths, you are going to get _more_ problems with moving the project to a different folder location, not less.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that ! I wanted to use the url from the root of my project because when I navigate from menu to another file or menu some pages don't work.1- first I dont know why the path from the root of my project dosn't work 2- is there a better way than relative paths to make all my links work where ever I am in the project

Comment: 1) Because `/stuff_here` when talking about files in PHP e.g. require, is from the root of the _filesystem_ not your project directory. 2) You're conflating internal paths, and URL paths, when using PHP, you'd try and use relative paths where possible, and possibly define a single constant that contains the path to the project from the root of the FS (see @misorude's comments), using `/stuff` in the URL, will link from the hostname / domain e.g. if you were on `http://example.com/page1/page2` and link to `/page3` that would be be equivalent to a link to `http://example.com/page3`.

Comment: First of all, you need to realize that you are talking about two different things here - file system paths, and URLs. Your server-side require works based on file system paths - your links on the client side are URLs. The URL structure _can_ map 1:1 onto the existing file system structure inside the project folder, but it doesn’t have to.

Comment: Problems with client-side relative URLs are due to the context in which they get used - `foo/bar.jpg` would point to two different absolute URLs, when you use it once in `/index.html`, and the second time in `/baz/index.html`. Using relative URLs that refer to the domain root - by starting with a leading slash - are the most common solution to _that_ problem.